# my first react app is throwing this error : Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to front-end & have just begun react js, (learning in VS code) I've setup my basic environment but when executing the 1st default "page.js" file the following error is being thrown:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\app\page.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

The code in my page.js file

```
import React from 'react'

const page = () => {
return (
    <div> page </div>
 )
}

export default page
```

given i am new to this environment I just can't seem to understand what's wrong here nor am I able to get any answers on how to fix this over the net, if someone can explain what is the problem & how to fix it & why is it happening, it would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using node to execute a file containing JSX. [JSX is a syntax extension of JavaScript](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) that isn't supported out of box. If you wanted to make this work you'd need to *transpile* the code using Babel or another tool to handle the JSX and convert it to something that node can execute. But I'd strongly advise against trying to do this yourself.

I'd suggest using different tooling. As of the today, the easiest way to get started with React would be with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/). These tools will take care of the tranpilation and bundling without exposing to all the details of configuring those tools.